# Making an Internet Handle as static member and Accessing it outside a thread.. Expert Advise Needed

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, httprequest, wininet

I have an Application that facilitates file uploading to the server using http request.
  I'm using HttpSendRequestEx and HttpEndRequest to do the file uploading.
  And it is working fine. And the uploading is performed inside a separate thread.
  in which the files to be uploaded are processed one by one.

Now a new requirement is that the user should be able to cancel the uploading at any time.
  As the uploading is performed inside a thread currently I dont have any control over that.

So as a work around, what I have done is, 
      When the user clicks the button for cancelling the upload,
      the following HINTERNET handles

```
  hSession returned from InternetOpen
  hConnect returned from InternetConnect
  hRequest returned from HttpOpenRequest
```

has been closed using InternetClosehandle function.

As these handles are used inside the thread, it is not able to access directly.
So I have declared these as static members of the class in whcich the thread runs. 
So that I can access it directly when the button click is occurred.

By doing this the request which is under process gets cancelled immediately. 
But I dont know whether this is a good way. So I would like to know whether there may have any security issues on proceeding this logic..

Also is there any option better than this....

Kindly have a comment on this. Expects an expert advise on this..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From a TCP socket point of view, this is a correct way to interrupt the request: It is perfectly legal to close a socket to stop and close a connection doing some work on a different thread.

That said, WinInet is more than a wrapper around a socket so we can't be sure that there's no resource or memory leak.

I would test it by writing a test program that creates a lot of such interrupted uploads and look for resource leaks on the Performance tab of the process in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). I would especially watch the Handles count and probably the Virtual Memory as well.

Also, before closing the handles, you could try to close the HTTP connection by calling HttpEndRequest(), which may possibly clean a little more things.