# How can I abort a request sent using wininet?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, httprequest, wininet

I have an MFC application in which I used to send a post request to the corresponding server.
It is an http request, for uploading a file.

But there is a requirement to abort the request sent. Like if the user is sending a large file and user should be able to cancel the request before it is completed.

I am using wininet apis, 
`HttpSendRequestEx`, `InternetWriteFile` and `HttpEndRequest`  for this.
but once the request is sent, I am not able to abort it in between unless the request is got completed or timed out.

Anyone please suggest an option for canceling a processing or sent request.

I have tried [closing the request handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614610/making-an-internet-handle-as-static-member-and-accessing-it-outside-a-thread-e), but still the request not gets aborted.

Any one please help..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "abort"? If you mean "force the server to stop processing the request after all the data is submitted and the server has initiated its processing", then there's nothing in the HTTP protocol to support that. You can close your handles and thus drop the connection, but the processing on the server will likely continue - it would just be unable to send the response back to you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue. I've started a thread which is blocking on a HttpSendRequest. I'd like to be able to cancel the request based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

From a client aspect, you can only abort/disconnect from the current operation by using the `InternetCloseHandle` routine.
This will instantly abort the request/operation from a client perspective, so the user can continue with another action.

But when the data has already been sent to the server, this will only result in not getting back a response!

As said by Igor, you cannot abort the processing at the server, as soon as the complete request (data) has been sent (at which point the client just waits to receive data from the server).

So you need to look at the point where you want to cancel 'sending' the request or revert the file addition at the server by sending a new 'delete' request from the client to the server, using the response of the first request (this response should contain information about the added file - like a key).